# Is there any good Haskell indentation script for Vim?

Tags: haskell, vim, indentation

Unfortunately, the one Haskell indent script I found (by motemen) breaks when it comes to Haddock comments:

```
-- |Docline 1, lorem ipsum<CR>
    -- Docline 2
^^^^ - an autoindent here, wtf
```

Would anyone happen to know about a better alternative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, so after even more googling, I found this indent script:

https://github.com/kana/vim-filetype-haskell/blob/master/indent/haskell.vim

It seems to work almost perfectly (ignores `if`..`then`.. `else` and `let`). But to be honest, the fact that it doesn't break my documentation makes it good enough right now :)

Answer (score 4):

I've no problems with [haskellmode-vim](http://projects.haskell.org/haskellmode-vim/)

edit: FWIW, I've found [this reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/xxxyi/is_there_a_standard_haskell_development_setup_for/)  recently. [vim2hs](https://github.com/dag/vim2hs) looks nice to me, also regarding indentation.

Comment: Thank's for this, upvoting the answer, the plugin is definitely useful, however, it did not fix the indentation issue. In fact, at least for me, it seemed to provide no indentation at all.